# Deploying logistic regression where variable is 'cut' in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a logistic regression model using `glm` that looks something like this:

`glm(formula = output ~ cut(X1,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X1:term + term:X5 - 1, family="binomial", data=mydata)`

When I use `summary(glm)` I get parameter outputs for each cut of `X1`. Suppose I wanted to implement / deploy this model. How do I handle each of the 'cut' derived parameters? For example, if the value is between `1` and `2` do I simply use the parameter associated with `2` multiplied by the value and set all others (since the value is not in their range) to `0`? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably not a good question for Stack Overflow (doesn't have much to do with programming - it's incidental that you're using R). You could migrate it to stats.stackexchange, but probably better you read a tutorial on regression with categorical variables. [This one looks all right](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/dummy_vars.htm), or [maybe this one](https://www.moresteam.com/whitepapers/download/dummy-variables.pdf)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Gregor, post as answer?

Comment: As it's still open, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Categorical variables, such as those you produced with `cut`, become *indicators* (AKA *dummy variables*) in regression. If your value is somewhere between 1 and 2, it's precise value doesn't matter - you have chosen to discard that information for your model. You simply add the parameter associated with the 1-to-2 range (times 1, if you want to think of it that way) and ignore all the others (or times 0, if you want to think of it that way).

This isn't really a programming or R-specific question - it's incidental that you're using R to bin your variable and fit your model. Any tutorial on regression with categorical variables should cover this. [This one looks all right](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/dummy_vars.htm), or maybe [this one (pdf link)](https://www.moresteam.com/whitepapers/download/dummy-variables.pdf).